# Batch script to get list of folder and subfolders and files with type

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a requirement to generate a text file which will consist the list of folders, subfolders and files. Separated by #

Something like this :

Report#Folder#EmployeesList#ExcelDocument

Where, Report is a folder containing an excel document by the name EmployeeList.

The script should run for the whole folder.

< Parent Name >#< Parent Type >#< Child Name >#< Child Type >

Comment: Ok, thank you for letting us know what your plans are. Once you have tried something and you fail, bring that code attempt here so we can assist.

Comment: Given that you appear to want `.\Report\EmployeesList.xlsx` to be output as `Report#Folder#EmployeesList#ExcelDocument`. What do you want output for `.\Report\SubFolder\Deeper Folder\EmployeesList.xlsx`? `Report#Folder#SubFolder#Folder#Deeper Folder#Folder#EmployeesList#ExcelDocument`? Also, as you should be aware after having taken the [tour], read through [ask], 
especially [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), your question is off topic. There are many sites, paid for, or otherwise, dedicated to programming to order, this is not one of those.

Comment: @Gerhard let me have a try and return with my findings.

Comment: @compo i need to dig deep into folder. Final result must always be a file.

Comment: @VedaanthPradhan, I asked a specific question, and linked several important pages for you to read and understand. Please answer the specific question I asked and read those links. If you are unable to show us what you want your content to look like for the subfolders, we cannot help you further. Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a blatant code request. No code was provided, no programming issue was specified, no links were offered as to reference material or their own attempts, and insufficient supporting information was included.

Answer (score 0):

Matching file detentions to their document type would be an utter pain.

Lets just list extentions at least for now and see if it gets you close enough for your needs.

Also it appears you only want to list the most recenr parent folder, is this correct?

If so, I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
@(Setlocal
  Echo off
  Set "OuputFilePath=C:\Some\Folder\Results.txt"
  Set "RootFolder=C:\Folder\path\to\root_folder"
  Set "FileGlob=*"
)

Call :Main

( Endlocal
  Exit /B 0
)

:Main
 For /F "tokens=*" %%D IN ('
    Dir /S /B /AD "%RootFolder%\" ') DO (
    For %%_ IN ( "%%D\%FileGlob%" ) DO (
      ECHO.%%~nD#Folder#%%~n_#%%~x__Document
    )
  )>>"%OuputFilePath%"
Goto :EOF
```

Comment: @GerhardBarnard, whilst I agree with most of the above, I'm not sure why you think the `( EndLocal` line will never be reached. The code should upon reaching `Goto :EOF` return to the point immediately following `Call :Main` which, as you can see, will be that `( Endlocal` line.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard `A)` It became extraneous while I wrote it in the shower as I changed my mind on how I was goinf to write the code, so it makes little difference whether or not removed. `2)` Personal preference to keep variable definitions in a code block at the top.  `D)` While I bothered to include `GOTO :EOF`, even if I had not, a `Call` to a function (here `:Main`) will return to the `Call` point on reaching the actual end of file, which would be the next line in this script example.  So I fail to see how it was missed, or why you would down-vote the answer given your comment's content.

Comment: As far as I know Ben, you have no way of knowing who down-voted your answer, however, as @Gerhard was mistaken on the last part of the comment, and the other parts of their comment were non critical to the result, I'm sure they'd have retracted it, had that been the case. That said, as there is another error in your script, not yet mentioned, that may be the reason for someone's down-vote. You have a missing opening parenthesis in your `:Main` section.

Comment: @Compo Yes, it is supposition on my part based off my analysys of the timing and the comment's contents.  That said, the opening `(` was an extra closing `)` but essentially the same difference, thansk for pointing it out, that was a helpful comment! :)

Comment: Ben, whilst that fixes the issue I reported, had you added an opening parenthesis instead of removing a closing one, it may have been better. I say that, because the output file would not need to have been effectively opened for writing for each directory and subdirectory within the root folder, but just once for the call to `:Main`. I would say though that it may be prudent in that case to first ensure that `%RootFolder%` exists and/or there are files matching `%FileGlob%` anywhere witihin the `%RootFolder%` tree.

Comment: TBF @Gerhard, Ben did specify in their opening lines that they weren't providing exactly what they understood to be the question posed, and the intent was to see if the OP could get closer to their goal! It therefore doesn't appear they have misunderstood or misread the question, simply offerered a script to output a similar result. Ben themselves imply that their answer was close, and you both therefore agree on this point.

Comment: @Compo Yeah, it's less writes, I just chose a happy medium, on speed verses risk that we'd over-run the resources available to process the results all in one go. Still Safest for that would be to stick the output directly on the `ECHO.` command